# Why python has limit for count of file handles?

Tags: python

I wrote a simple code to test how many files may be open in python script:

```
for i in xrange(2000):
    fp = open('files/file_%d' % i, 'w')
    fp.write(str(i))
    fp.close()

fps = []
for x in xrange(2000):
    h = open('files/file_%d' % x, 'r')
    print h.read()
    fps.append(h)
```

and I get the exception:

```
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'files/file_509'
```

Comment: on fedora 14 and python 2.7 I got this error on 1021

Comment: @wiso, +stdin, stdout, stderr makes 1024 - where have I seen that number before?

Comment: You should use `try..finally` or `with` to safely close a file. To your problem: maybe you want to tell us what you are going to do because want your code does makes no sense at all for me.

Comment: @gnibber: `ulimit -n` gives me 1024. I think you need to count also `/usr/lib64/python2.7/atexit.py` and `/home/xyz/.pystartup` as opened files.

Comment: Were you to try this in another language on the same operating system, you'll quicky discover that this is not a Python limitation.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The number of open files is limited by the operating system. On linux you can type

```
ulimit -n
```

to see what the limit is. If you are root, you can type

```
ulimit -n 2048
```

now your program will run ok (as root) since you have lifted the limit to 2048 open files

Comment: +1, i will add if you want to check the limit using a python code use `import resource; print resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)`.

Comment: Apparently, you don't need to be root to change it (I just tried!)

Answer (score 15):

I see same behavior on Windows when running your code. The limit exists from C runtime. You can use win32file to change the limit value:

```
import win32file

print win32file._getmaxstdio()
```

The above shall give you 512, which explains the failure at #509 (+stdin, stderr, stdout as others have already stated)

Execute the following and your code shall run fine:

```
win32file._setmaxstdio(2048)
```

Note that 2048 is the hard limit, though (hard limit of the underlying C Stdio). As a result, executing the _setmaxstdio with a value greater than 2048 fails for me.

Comment: to make this work, I first had to do this install: 

`pip install pywin32`

Comment: Also note that as of 2022, the C runtime libraries now support an upper limit of 8192 open files, not 2048. See [Microsoft's documentation on the `_setmaxstdio function.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmaxstdio?view=msvc-170#remarks)

Answer (score 11):

To check change the limit of open file handles on Linux, you can use the Python module [resource](http://pymotw.com/2/resource/):

```
import resource

# the soft limit imposed by the current configuration
# the hard limit imposed by the operating system.
soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
print 'Soft limit is ', soft 

# For the following line to run, you need to execute the Python script as root.
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (3000, hard))
```

On Windows, I do as Punit S suggested:

```
import platform

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    import win32file
    win32file._setmaxstdio(2048)
```

Comment: I noticed I don't have to be root to run `setrlimit` in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely because the operating system has a limit for the number of files that an application can have open.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows one can get or set the limit with the built-in ctypes library:

```py
import ctypes
print("Before: {}".format(ctypes.windll.msvcrt._getmaxstdio()))
ctypes.windll.msvcrt._setmaxstdio(2048)
print("After: {}".format(ctypes.windll.msvcrt._getmaxstdio()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a Python problem, do this:

```
for x in xrange(2000):
    with open('files/file_%d' % x, 'r') as h:
        print h.read()
```

The following is a **very** bad idea.

```
fps.append(h)
```

Comment: Whether this is a bad idea or not depends on what you're doing. Even Guido himself uses this strategy of holding onto open files in a particular sorting algorithm: http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/sorting-million-32-bit-integers-in-2mb.html

Comment: @S.Lott: Can you explain why you think fps.append(h) would be a bad idea (and which alternative would you suggest)?

Answer (score -1):

The append is needed so the garbage collector does not clean up and close the files