# Python: Which command increases the number of open files on Windows?

Tags: python, file, io

There seems to be lots of questions on this topic bit I can't seem to find what exactly I should call inside my python script to increase the open file limit ? I know that I need to use the `_setmaxstdio` on C level but I am not sure how to call it in python. Any ideas ?

Comment: Isn't @NorthCat answer OK? If yes, please mark it as so. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774724/why-python-has-limit-for-count-of-file-handles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `win32file` from [pywin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32):

```
import win32file
print win32file._getmaxstdio() #512

win32file._setmaxstdio(1024)
print win32file._getmaxstdio() #1024
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution with the built-in ctypes library:

```py
import ctypes
print("Before: {}".format(ctypes.windll.msvcrt._getmaxstdio()))
ctypes.windll.msvcrt._setmaxstdio(2048)
print("After: {}".format(ctypes.windll.msvcrt._getmaxstdio()))
```