# Pygraphviz crashes after drawing 170 graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am using pygraphviz to create a large number of graphs for different configurations of data. I have found that no matter what information is put in the graph the program will crash after drawing the 170th graph. There are no error messages generated the program just stops. Is there something that needs to be reset if drawing this many graphs?

I am running Python 3.7 on a Windows 10 machine, Pygraphviz 1.5, and graphviz 2.38

```
    for graph_number in range(200):
        config_graph = pygraphviz.AGraph(strict=False, directed=False, compound=True, ranksep='0.2', nodesep='0.2')

        # Create Directory
        if not os.path.exists('Graph'):
            os.makedirs('Graph')

        # Draw Graph      
        print('draw_' + str(graph_number))
        config_graph.layout(prog = 'dot')
        config_graph.draw('Graph/'+str(graph_number)+'.png')
```

Comment: PyGraphviz has a github source code repository with an Issues tab -have you tried asking there?

Comment: Did you check the memory usage of the program / increase. Maybe the memory fre is not correct. Did you try moving the for statement directly before the `# Draw Graph`? Where did you load the dot code that should be drawn?

Comment: To add to what @albert said, a memory issue seems the most likely problem if you are running a 32-bit version of Python. However, if this was the case, there should be a way of reducing memory usage (which would then be the answer to your question).

Comment: @draB1 please check the comments and give feedback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to constantly reproduce the behavior with:

1. *Python 3.7.6* (*pc064* (*64bit*), then also with *pc032*)
2. *PyGraphviz 1.5* (that I built - available for download at **[[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - Various software built on various platforms.](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries)** (under *PyGraphviz*, naturally).
   Might also want to check [[SO]: Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54890705/4788546))
3. *Graphviz 2.42.2* ((*pc032*) same as ***#2.***)

I suspected an ***U**ndefined **B**ehavior* somewhere in the code, even if the behavior was **precisely** the same:

- *OK* for ***169*** graphs
- Crash for ***170***

Did some debugging (added some *print(f)* statements in *agraph.py*, and *cgraph.dll* (*write.c*)).
*PyGraphviz* invokes *Graphviz*'s tools (*.exe*s) for many operations. For that, it uses *subprocess.Popen* and communicates with the child process via its 3 available streams (*stdin*, *stdout*, *stderr*).

From the beginning I noticed that `170 * 3 = 510` (awfully close to *512* (*0x200*)), but didn't pay as much attention as I should have until later (mostly because the *Python* process (running the code below) **had no more than *~150* open handles in *Task Manager* (*TM*) and also *Process Explorer* (*PE*)**).

However, a bit of *Google*ing revealed:

- [[SO]: Is there a limit on number of open files in Windows (@stackprogrammer's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/870224/4788546) (and from here)
- [[MS.Learn]: _setmaxstdio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmaxstdio) (which states (***emphasis*** is mine)):

  > C run-time I/O now supports up to ***8,192*** files open simultaneously at the [low I/O level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/low-level-i-o). This level includes files opened and accessed using the **_open**, **_read**, and **_write** family of I/O functions. By default, up to 512 files can be open simultaneously at the [stream I/O level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/stream-i-o?). This level includes files opened and accessed using the **fopen**, **fgetc**, and **fputc** family of functions. The limit of ***512*** open files at the stream I/O level can be increased to a maximum of ***8,192*** by use of the **_setmaxstdio** function.
- [[SO]: Python: Which command increases the number of open files on Windows? (@NorthCat's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24148806/4788546)

Below is your code that I modified for debugging and reproducing the error. It needs (for code shortness' sake, as same thing can be achieved via *CTypes*) the *PyWin32* package (`python -m pip install pywin32`).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
#import time

import pygraphviz as pgv
import win32file as wfile


def handle_graph(idx, dir_name):
    graph_name = "draw_{:03d}".format(idx)
    graph_args = {
        "name": graph_name,
        "strict": False,
        "directed": False,
        "compound": True,
        "ranksep": "0.2",
        "nodesep": "0.2",
    }
    graph = pgv.AGraph(**graph_args)
    # Draw Graph      
    img_base_name = graph_name + ".png"
    print("  {:s}".format(img_base_name))
    graph.layout(prog="dot")
    img_full_name = os.path.join(dir_name, img_base_name)
    graph.draw(img_full_name)
    graph.close()  # !!! Has NO (visible) effect, but I think it should be called anyway !!!


def main(*argv):
    print("OLD max open files: {:d}".format(wfile._getmaxstdio()))
    # 513 is enough for your original code (170 graphs), but you can set it up to 8192
    #wfile._setmaxstdio(513)  # !!! COMMENT this line to reproduce the crash !!!
    print("NEW max open files: {:d}".format(wfile._getmaxstdio()))

    dir_name = "Graph"
    # Create Directory
    if not os.path.isdir(dir_name):
        os.makedirs(dir_name)

    #ts_global_start = time.time()
    start = 0
    count = 170
    #count = 1
    step_sleep = 0.05
    for i in range(start, start + count):
        #ts_local_start = time.time()
        handle_graph(i, dir_name)
        #print("  Time: {:.3f}".format(time.time() - ts_local_start))
        #time.sleep(step_sleep)
    handle_graph(count, dir_name)
    #print("Global time: {:.3f}".format(time.time() - ts_global_start - step_sleep * count))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q060876623> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> OLD max open files: 512
> NEW max open files: 513
>   draw_000.png
>   draw_001.png
>   draw_002.png
>
> ...
>
>   draw_167.png
>   draw_168.png
>   draw_169.png
>
> Done.
> ```

**Conclusions**:

- Apparently, some file handles (*fd*s) are open, although they are not "seen" by *TM* or *PE* (probably they are on a lower level). However I don't know why this happens (is it a *MS UCRT* bug?), but from what I am concerned, once a child process ends, its streams should be closed, but I don't know how to force it (**this would be a proper fix**)
- Also, the behavior (**crash**) when attempting to **write** (**not open**) to a *fd* (above the limit), seems a bit strange
- As a workaround, the *max* open *fd*s number can be increased. Based on the following inequality: **`3 * (graph_count + 1) <= max_fds`**, you can get an idea about the numbers. From there, if you set the limit to *8192* (I didn't test this) you should be able handle ***2729*** graphs (assuming that there are no additional *fd*s opened by the code)

**Side notes**:

- While investigating, I ran into or noticed several adjacent issues, that I tried to fix:

  - *Graphviz*:

    - [[GitLab]: graphviz/graphviz - [Issue #1481]: MSB4018 The NativeCodeAnalysis task failed unexpectedly.](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/merge_requests/1340) (**merged on *200406***)
  - *PyGraphviz*:

    - [[GitHub]: pygraphviz/pygraphviz - AGraph Graphviz handle close mechanism](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/pull/216) (**merged on *200720***)
- There's also an issue open for this behavior (probably the same author): [[GitHub]: pygraphviz/pygraphviz - Pygraphviz crashes after drawing 170 graphs](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/213)

Comment: This is impressive detective work. What would happen if the OP called `subprocess.run` directly *without* using the standard streams, i.e. the streams set to `DEVNULL`?

Comment: @RolandSmith: Thx. it's *PyGraphviz* which does the call. I tried modifying `close_fds=True` but it didn't have any effect. Not sure how *OP* could do something without modifying the *pgv* code. But even if so, it wouldn't work because the child process needs to be interacted with and the *subprocess* hi level wrappers don't allow that.

Comment: I meant *without* using PyGraphviz.

Comment: Hmm, don't know. But I imagine that a lot of code should be written. I am not a *Graphviz* expert, so I didn't even think going down on that road. But based on what I see in *agraph.py* (and my previous comment test), I tend to incline that it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Brilliant detective work! Let's make sure this ends up in respective repo issues ❤️

Comment: @DimaTisnek: Thanks. Apparently there is a *PyGraphviz* bug: https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/213.

Answer (score -1):

I tried you code and it generated 200 graphs with no problem (I also tried with 2000).

My suggestion is to use these versions of the packages, I installed a conda environment on mac os with python 3.7 :

graphviz                  2.40.1               hefbbd9a_2

pygraphviz                1.3              py37h1de35cc_1

Comment: I don't think this provides a real answer as you worked on a mac and OP on Windows. Furthermore you used different versions of graphviz (newer) and pygraphviz (older). Problem might be system dependent.

Comment: I agree that this does not explain what happens for the OP. But this gives the idea that there is nothing wrong with the code, there is no reset to perform (which is the OP question). Moreover, using these versions may provide a real solution for windows also.

Comment: The OP code might not be wrong, but there might be some problems with: pygrapviz 1.5 or the used python version (3.7 is the general name, might be a sub 3.7.x problem), might be a memory leak / garbage collection problem ... but we won't know till OP answers on the questions.

Comment: Agreed. I still think that my answer may provide a solution which is worth trying.