# Errno 24 Too many open files when using Psychopy

Tags: psychopy, movies

I have 40 videos that I would like to present in a random loop 15 times. Even though the experiment runs all the way through my .csv file output does not save and I get an error saying too many files are open

If I change the number of repetitions to 5 it works and saves all the data.

Anything above 5 has the error [Errno 24] Too many open files and saves only the .log file.

Is there  piece of code I can add in my .py to close each file after its shown? Or is it an Operating System problem? I use Windows 7. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Below the entire output message.

```
################## Running: F:\Movies\Block 1_lastrun.py ##################
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “U:\Final draft\Block 1_lastrun.py”, line 189, in
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\visual\movie3.py”, line 134, in init
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\visual\movie3.py”, line 180, in loadMovie
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py”, line 81, in init
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py”, line 32, in init
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py”, line 256, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\subprocess.py”, line 745, in    init
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\atexit.py”, line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\data\experiment.py”, line 366, in close
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\data\experiment.py”, line 351, in saveAsPickle
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\tools\filetools.py”, line 149, in openOutputFile
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\codecs.py”, line 896, in open
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: u’U:\Final draft\data/_BM-Stimulation_2018_Jun_13_1535.psydat’
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\atexit.py”, line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
func(*targs, **kargs)
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\data\experiment.py”, line 366, in close
self.saveAsPickle(self.dataFileName)
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\data\experiment.py”, line 351, in saveAsPickle
fileCollisionMethod=fileCollisionMethod) as f:
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\tools  \filetools.py”, line 149, in openOutputFile
f = codecs.open(fileName, mode=mode, encoding=encoding)
File “C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\codecs.py”, line 896, in open
file = builtin.open(filename, mode, buffering)
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: u’F:\Movies\data/_BM-     Stimulation_2018_Jun_26_1533.psydat’
```

Comment: Can you post the code from "Block 1_lastrun.py"? You're probably running into something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774724/why-python-has-limit-for-count-of-file-handles

Comment: Formatting of code

Comment: Thank you Sniperd!

Comment: Thanks for your reply alexforrence. Looking into the link you posted I suspect you are right!