# Using pywin32 commands in Django

Tags: python, django, pywin32

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28212496/9611931 a replacement for ulimit in Windows and I want to execute following lines of code in Django project. Where should I set this for Django.??

```
import win32file
win32file._setmaxstdio(2048)
```

Background : Specifically I want to remove Cstack limit error from Django App and i am trying this ulimit solution to remove this error

Comment: pip install django-windows-tools

Comment: i can also import pywin32 or pypiwin32 right? but where should i write these 2 lines inside some setup ? or any view ? because they are going to set for once?